# Is it possible to have different domains for each node?

Tags: 7

I have some nodes that I want to access them by different URL domains. For example:

```
XX.XX.XX.XX/node/1 --> domain1.com
XX.XX.XX.XX/node/2 --> domain2.com
XX.XX.XX.XX/node/3 --> domain3.com
```

Also the nodes have a file field where the admins can upload a pdf file and the users can download it, so:

```
XX.XX.XX.XX/PATH-TO-UPLOADED-PDF --> domain1.com/PATH-TO-PDF
XX.XX.XX.XX/PATH-TO-UPLOADED-PDF --> domain2.com/PATH-TO-PDF
XX.XX.XX.XX/PATH-TO-UPLOADED-PDF --> domain3.com/PATH-TO-PDF
```

Is that possible to do with Drupal? I will buy the domains only if I know that is 100% possible.

Of course, I know that there are better solutions than Drupal, but I want to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Domain module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain), but since you say there are better solutions than Drupal, you should probably go with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your node table by adding a field called node_domain for example, and then you can filter display of your nodes by this field compared to current domain of your application.

Hope this can help you.